# What does the term "Job-Embedded" mean?

Tags: terminology

I have seen the term "Job-Embedded" in proffessional development papers, but I didnt find any well description of its meaning, what does it mean?

Comment: I don't know about *job embedded* but here is a wikipedia link to [*job embeddedness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_embeddedness). Maybe  "Job-Embedded" in proffessional development context means improving an employee's performance?.

Answer (score 1):

@Arrowfar suggested it, and I just searched for "job-embedded" (with quotes) on both Google and Wikipedia - interesting results...

I am *not sure* **job-embedded** is connected (aside from sounding similar) to **job embeddedness** as defined by Wikipedia.  However, what I do see is a very stable use of "*job-embedded professional development*", from which I dare to hazard a guess that it's some kind of training program that *teachers* (this is what I see the most) undergo while continuing their normal job activities.  What exactly it consists of, is not clear and I don't want to speculate.

Essentially it appears to be "on the job training" of sorts, specific to teachers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I had never encountered this term "job-embedded" before I read your question, though the term *on-the-job training (OJT)* wasn't new for me. My first guess when I read the title before opening this question was that it would be about something "embedded in the job". Judging from the PDF I found (see below), I think "embedded in the job" isn't very far off.

From the PDF file (titled *[Job-Embedded Professional Development: What It Is, Who Is Responsible, and How to Get It Done Well](http://learningforward.org/docs/pdf/jobembeddedpdbrief.pdf)*),

> #### What Is Job-Embedded Professional Development?
>
> Job-embedded professional development (JEPD) refers to **teacher learning that is grounded in day-to-day teaching practice** and is designed to enhance teachers’ content-specific instructional practices with the intent of improving student learning (Darling-Hammond & McLaughlin, 1995; Hirsh, 2009). It is primarily school or classroom based and is integrated into the workday,
>   consisting of teachers assessing and finding solutions for authentic and immediate problems of practice as part of a cycle of continuous improvement (Hawley & Valli, 1999; National Staff Development Council, 2010). JEPD is a shared, ongoing process that is locally rooted and makes a direct connection between learning and application in daily practice, thereby requiring active
>   teacher involvement in cooperative, inquiry-based work (Hawley & Valli, 1999). High-quality JEPD also is aligned with state standards for student academic achievement and any related local educational agency and school improvement goals (Hirsh, 2009).
>
> <sup>*(emphasis mine)*</sup>

In my humble opinion, this seems like teacher's jargon. It's also worth noting that searching for `"job-embedded"` on Google returns only 381 results. And the PDF I linked to in this answer is probably the best source that clarifies what *job-embedded* is all about.

Answer (score 0):

It's gobbeldy-glop nonsensical human resources jargon indicating bold new paradigms designed to reinforce career based recompense-induced reductions.